# User input text box to display on same page

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a text box for user input, how can I take the input a user enters and display it on the same page (without reloading or redirecting to a different page). (example, comments on YouTube videos)

Here is my code for the user input text box so far:

```
 <div class="container">
  <form>
    <label for="post" id="post">What's on your mind?</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="post-box" name="post">
    <button>Comment</button>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? It require DOM manipulation and event listener. Make sure refer this two to help you more. :D

First, add event listener to listen any changes on keyboard press for the form (even though i just put it globally). Here all the your listener references https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Second change the innerHTML to display ur name. Here for your references
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

```
<html>
<p id="p-display"></p>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label for="post" id="post">What's on your mind?</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="post-box" name="post">
    <button id="btn-submit">Comment</button>
  </form>
 </div> 

</html>

<script>
var post_item = document.getElementById("post-box");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-submit");

addEventListener("keyup", function changeValue()
{
console.log(post_item.value);
document.getElementById("p-display").innerHTML = post_item.value;
});

</script>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but the user text from the input box shows up in the appropriate spot for a split second before vanishing.

Comment: I guess it has nothing to do with the spot that u desire. The changeValue() just triggered when users done press the key on keyboard and print it in inner html tag. You might **declare the id in wrong html tag.** revise more on html tag and innerhtml javascript